# npm script with time function throws "sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")"

Tags: node.js, npm

## Problem Description

When I wrap any script in a `time()` function on a linux machine, I get following error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

## Steps to reproduce issue

```
> mkdir hello-world
> cd hello-world
> npm init
> vim package & update test script to `"test": "time(echo \"Error: no test specified\")"`
> npm test
```

## Package.json

```
{
  "name": "hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "time(echo \"Error: no test specified\")"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

## More

Running the same command on terminal results in:

```
> time(echo \"Error: no test specified\")
"Error: no test specified"

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

## Versions, I am using

```
"node": "~6.9.5",
"npm": "~3.10.10"
```

Comment: add package.json please, most probably you dont have anything relevant under scripts > test and then you are running npm test , it checks the script runs its command and throws error